# Can no longer write to my external hard drive

Tags: command-line, permissions, ftp

I have an external hard drive mounted to my /home directory. It worked perfectly since day one. But I haven't touched it in a while and for some reason it won't let me transfer files to it via FTP. Here's the output from filezilla

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
Status: Starting upload of E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4
Command:    put "E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4" "video.mp4"
Command:    local:E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4 => remote:/home/matt/pstash/video.mp4
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Connecting to rz.theswagshack.net:21549...
Status: Using username "matt". 
Status: Connected to rz.theswagshack.net
Status: Starting upload of E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/home/matt/pstash"...
Status: Listing directory /home/matt/pstash
Command:    put "E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4" "video.mp4"
Command:    local:E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4 => remote:/home/matt/pstash/video.mp4
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Connecting to rz.theswagshack.net:21549...
Status: Using username "matt". 
Status: Connected to rz.theswagshack.net
Status: Starting upload of E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/home/matt/pstash"...
Status: Listing directory /home/matt/pstash
Command:    put "E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4" "video.mp4"
Command:    local:E:\Users\Matt\Matt\UwU\video.mp4 => remote:/home/matt/pstash/video.mp4
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Connecting to rz.theswagshack.net:21549...
Status: Using username "matt". 
Status: Connected to rz.theswagshack.net
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/home/matt/pstash"...
Status: Listing directory /home/matt/pstash
Status: Directory listing of "/home/matt/pstash" successful
```

ls -l shows

```
drwxr-x--x 10 matt matt 4096 Jan 15 22:05  pstash
```

I tried chmod +x /home/matt/pstash too and it didn't help.

I tried to login via CLI and wget a file in the same folder & the same user and that works perfectly.

kind of out of ideas